# django rest framework extra actions for routing to specific financial statement of data set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, router, django-rest-viewsets

I have a viewset for stocks by ticker/company which corresponds to the urls.  localhost:8000/stocks/AAPL works for example.

what I want is an extra action to route to localhost:8000/stocks/AAPL/income_statement, but I cant figure out how to create the extra action using the `detail_route` decorator below.

I've commented in the code base where I am having troubles

views.py

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer

    # !!! this is what I don't know what to do !!!!
    @detail_route(methods=["get"])
    def get_is(self, request, statement):
        stock = self.get_object()
        serializer = IncomeStatementSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"stocks", views.StockViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: FYI: `detail_route` has depreciated, Which DRF version are you using?

Comment: version for drf is 3.11.1 . . . it wasn't running the server, so thank you to begin with. good catch